# I need help with commas

Tags: punctuation

I'm not sure if the comma before the word "and" is properly used in the sentence below this paragraph. I believe a comma is not needed because the second clause is a subordinate clause, but I am not completely sure. I'm trying to improve my grammar and would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you.

"Your country's moral superiority is a scam, and has been exposed as what it is numerous times".

Comment: Yes. It's needed for the literary effect in the place.

Comment: Would the sentence be correct If "it" is placed before "and": "Your country's moral superiority is a scam, and it has been exposed as what it is numerous times"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a second clause conjoined with "and" to the first.  You have a two-part compound *predicate*:

> (*is* a scam)<sub>1</sub> and (*has been exposed*)<sub>2</sub>.

Ordinarily, commas do not separate the two parts of a compound, but leaving out the comma will leave you with a problem of style, what Steven Pinker calls a garden path -- a construct that will mislead the reader, who will see

> Your country's moral superiority is a scam and ....

and may expect the second part of a two-part compound *object*:

> Your country's moral superiority is (a scam)<sub>1</sub> and (*an outrage*)<sub>2</sub>....

instead of the second part of a compound verb.  Leaving in the comma is one choice.  Another is to rephrase to get around the problem:

> Your country's moral superiority is a scam that has been exposed for
>   what it is numerous times".